# Adding multiple times in (HH.mm)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

data in sqlserver.
calling it in gridview
how do i add all the time in the column, i have 4 columns to calculate for different total time.
for example :
time 1 = 256.20 (HH.mm)
time 2 = 257.41 (HH.mm)
time 3 = 114.50 (HH.mm)
time 4 = 371.20 (HH.mm)
total = 1000.11 (HH.mm)

the total will keep on increasing but the format must be hours and minutes.
i added 2 time for the time 1 from above using string split
doing it in C#.net

thanking you in advance.

thank you very much @CodingYoshi

```
>        //string time1 = TextBox1.Text;
         //string time2 = TextBox2.Text;

        //string[] part1 = time1.Split('.');
        //int h1 = int.Parse(part1[0]);
        //int m1 = int.Parse(part1[1]);

        //string[] part2 = time2.Split('.');
        //int h2 = int.Parse(part2[0]);
        //int m2 = int.Parse(part2[1]);

        //int totalHours = h1 + h2;
        //int totalMinutes = m1 + m2;

        //if (totalMinutes >= 60)
        //{
        //    totalHours = totalHours + 1;
        //    totalMinutes = totalMinutes % 60;
        //}

        var times = new List<string>
        {
            TextBox1.Text,TextBox2.Text
        };

        TimeSpan total = new TimeSpan();
        foreach (var thisString in times)
        {
            var split = thisString.Split('.');
            total = total.Add(new TimeSpan(int.Parse(split[0]), int.Parse(split[1]), 0));
        }

        var totalHours = (int)total.TotalHours;
        var totalMinutes = total.Minutes;

        TextBox3.Text = totalHours.ToString() + "." + totalMinutes.ToString();
```

from gridview

```
SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from totalHours";
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    TimeSpan total = new TimeSpan();

    var times = new List<string> ();

    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        times.Add((GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text));
    }

    foreach (var thisString in times)
    {
        var split = thisString.Split('.');
        total = total.Add(new TimeSpan(int.Parse(split[0]), int.Parse(split[1]), 0));
    }

    var totalHours = (int)total.TotalHours;
    var totalMins = total.Minutes;

    Label2.Text = totalHours.ToString() + "." + totalMins.ToString();
```

thank you again @CodingYoshi

Comment: Is it the or duration? 256.20 is not a valid time value? How can you display 1000 with 2 digits?

Comment: that's the hours. 256 hours 20 minutes, 257 hours 41 mins, 114 hours 50 mins, 371 hours 20 mins. total - 1000 hours 11 mins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I am adding 2 of them and you can do the rest:

```
var t1 = new TimeSpan(256, 20, 0);
var t2 = new TimeSpan(257, 41, 0);
var tTotal = t1.Add(t2).ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss");
```

`tTotal` will display the days, hours, minutes and seconds of adding `t1` and `t2`;

---

If you want to do them using a loop, you can do it like this:

```
var times = new List<string>
{
    "256.20",
    "257.41",
    "114.50",
    "371.20",
    "1000.11"
};

TimeSpan total = new TimeSpan();
foreach (var thisString in times)
{
    var split = thisString.Split('.');
    total = total.Add(new TimeSpan(int.Parse(split[0]), int.Parse(split[1]), 0));
}
var totalDisplay = total.ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss");
```

---

If you want the total hours and minutes:

```
var totalHours = (int)total.TotalHours;
var totalMins = total.Minutes;
```

Comment: i want to add hours and mins only. is there any way to do it

Comment: for var totalDisplay = total.ToString(@"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss");<br> Can i just use var totalDisplay = total.ToString(@"hh\.mm");

Comment: @DeepShah you have been given quite something to work with. Considering that you have provided no code whatsoever in your question, you should be happy about that. It‘s time for you to get to work now and write your own program.

Comment: @DeepShah why don't you try that and see if it will give you what you need.